# Deploying Com Interop into sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint

I have a com interop dll (zkemkeeper.dll) that i have to register and use, i wonder how can i deploy that to the SharePoint server using SharePoint package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot deploy COM or COM Interop DLL to SP farm by SP solution. You need to install the component on every SP server in the farm by other means.

1. Create an MSI installer to be executed on every machine. MSI can be rolled out automatically too.
2. Provide a PowerShell script to be executed on every machine. PowerShell can be run remotely too.
3. Deploy a timer job with your solution that would be executed after the installation automatically or manually and would write to the registry the necessary COM stuff.

The first two options are my favourite because they shouldn't cause technical problems at the customer. The third one appears to promise installation without visiting every machine but the Timer Service user identity would need permission to write to the local registry which may not always be granted; and you'd have to resort to 1. or 2. anyway.

You should think about switching over to ASP.NET or .NET components on the long term. There are many components available in pure .NET that can be deployed by SP solutions. You can also consider pure HTML/JavaScript controls. I would probably go for the option 1. and invest the saved time to other architecture without the COM Interop.

--- Ferda

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sharepoint 2010, see [How to: Add and Remove Additional Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231595.aspx).

See also:

- [Deploying custom dll's in SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092544/deploying-custom-dlls-in-sharepoint-2010)
- [Visual Studio - SharePoint 2010 - Include Assembly > Quick Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353881/visual-studio-sharepoint-2010-include-assembly-quick-question)
- [Include 3rd party dll in the Sharepoint project while packaging the wsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521697/include-3rd-party-dll-in-the-sharepoint-project-while-packaging-the-wsp)
- [visual studio does not copy assembly into gac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422724/visual-studio-does-not-copy-assembly-into-gac)
- [How to install a WSP that has dependant assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477646/how-to-install-a-wsp-that-has-dependant-assemblies)

Comment: sir im talking about a com interop assemly which needs to be registered by regsvr32 command, only copying the assembly wont register it

Answer (score -1):

`Interop.zkemkeeper.dll regsvr32 error` or `InitializeComponent`

Then you need done the step following:

1. Go to the website: http://www.zktechnology.com
2. Download ->Software Download->ZK Access for C3 panels
3. Extract files
4. Install
5. Open visual studio -> Solution Project->references-> Add Interop.zkemkeeper.dll

Good luck